# Sphinx search for a part of word

Tags: php, search, full-text-search, sphinx

I installed SphinxSearch and configured it correctly, every thing is working fine in CLI also searching via the browser.

my problem is that I get results just for 'the whole word', for example : 
I want to get all words star with "pre" like 'preconditions, presides', so when I type pre I suppose that I would get the previous two words.

I researched a lot about it, also I found many questions here, but still getting the same results.

The following is part of my config file :

```
index pbettingIndex
{
    source = src1
    path = /server/sphinx/data/src1Index
    docinfo = extern
    mlock = 0
    morphology = stem_en
    min_word_len = 1 
    charset_type = utf-8
    enable_star = 1

    #enable_wildcard = 1
    min_infix_len = 2
    #infix_fields = event_name
    #min_prefix_len = 1 
 }
```

In my PHP code I tried to change all available match-modes

```
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY); // etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable searching by 'star', You must call

```
    $cl->query('*pre*', 'index');
```

so did you do?

documentation: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/conf-enable-star.html

Comment: old question but worth adding for others, use expand_keywords=1